# Explicitly casting an object to another object of a generic type in C# that's available only at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, types, casting

I am trying to cast some type to another generic type, but I can't find any solution for how this could be done in my specific situation. The simplified situation is as follows. Note that this might seem very strange and artificial, but it's just to point out my problem. The actual application makes more sense... :-)

```
// Raw data coming from some source
public class RawDataType { }    

// Abstract base class for structured data representing this raw data
public abstract class AbstractListDataType { }

// Generates lists of structured data
public class ListGenerator<TListDataType> where TListDataType : AbstractListDataType
{
    public List<TListDataType> GenerateList()
    {
        // Get the data from some mysterious place
        RawDataType data = new RawDataType() { ... }
        // Cast it to the required structured data type
        return new List<TListDataType>() { data as TListDataType ??? }
    }
}
```

Then in **another assembly**, that is being loaded at **runtime**, there are some concrete representations for this raw data. The ListGenerator itself absolutely has no knowledge about these types. After the assembly containing the structured data types has been loaded, it is being inspected with reflection to see what kinds of structered data can be generated.

```
// Two types of structured application data that can be created from the raw data
public class ListDataTypeA : AbstractListDataType 
{ 
    public static explicit operator ListDataTypeA(RawDataType data) { ... }
}
public class ListDataTypeB : AbstractListDataType 
{ 
    public static explicit operator ListDataTypeB(RawDataType data) { ... }
}
```

Of course,

```
data as TListDataType
```

doesn't make sense. How can I achieve a dynamic cast from RawDataType to i.e. ListDataTypeA for which I know there is an explicit conversion which is available but only at runtime?

Edit:

It seems the following **works**:

```
(TListDataType)(dynamic)data
```

I find this extremely ugly. Considering the situation I described here, is there a better way to go?

Comment: That may look ugly, but it makes perfect sense considering what is going on under the hood.  It probably would look less ugly if `data` was `dynamic` from the beginning.

Comment: This is basically exactly what the DLR is for... Follow the advice of @RobertHarvey and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

If `dynamic` approach does not look good for you - try more standard Factory pattern.

Since explicit cast is resolve at compile time you will have to call that method yourself by hand (i.e. via reflection).

I'd go another route and add "Load" method to `AbstractListDataType` or have factory method/class to create items of desired class:

```
 public abstract class AbstractListDataType { 
     public void Load(RawData data)....
 }

 public class ListGenerator<TListDataType> 
     where TListDataType : AbstractListDataType, new()

     public List<TListDataType> GenerateList()
     {
        RawDataType data = new RawDataType() { ... }
        var item = new T();
        item.Load(data);
        return new List<TListDataType>() { item };
     }
 }
```

Or factory approach:

```
 public abstract class ListItemFactory<T> 
 {
      abstract public T CreateFromRawData(RawDataType data);
 }

 public class ListGenerator<TListDataType> 
     where TListDataType : AbstractListDataType
 {
     ListItemFactory<TListDataType> factory;
     public ListGenerator<TListDataType>(ListItemFactory<TListDataType> factory)
     {
         this.factory = factory;
     }

     public List<TListDataType> GenerateList()
     {
        RawDataType data = new RawDataType() { ... }
        return new List<TListDataType>() { factory.CreateFromRawData(data)};
     }
 }
```